# Travelling before entering India with UK visa

Tags: visas, india, france

I've just applied for my Indian visa as a UK resident, but I'm planning on going to France beforehand, then flying to India from there. Will going to France before India be a considered a problem? As long as my visa is accepted, will everything be OK?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you clarify what is your concern regarding a visa?  As it stands it's unclear.

Comment: I essentially have concerns with the country of departure. Will going to France before India be a considered a problem?

Comment: By whom? It's not a problem if you're admitted legally to France...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why there should be a problem. You are legally permitted to enter a country with a visa. Simple.

If you are coming from a country in which you are legally permitted and going to a country which legally permits you to enter, you should have no issues.

Of course this assumes the fact that you are in good standing while in the other country (in this case France).